# How to build a file path correctly by using php?

Tags: php, security, filesystems

I have a directory and a dynamic file name. Are there any functions I can use to make sure it is impossible to break out from the specified directory?

for example:

```
secure_path('/tmp/', 'file.txt') -> /tmp/file.txt
secure_path('/tmp/', '../file.txt') -> /tmp/file.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only working in the single directory and not subdirectories below you could do

```
$file = "/tmp/".basename($input);
```

Which should give you the filename at the end of any path given in input, and append it to the directory you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Use `realpath()` to get a canonic form of the path, and eliminate any `../`-s. Then verify that it contains the full path of the directory you want to contain it to.

Such as:

```
$path = "/tmp/file.txt";
$directory = "{full path of your files directory}";

if (strpos(realpath($path), $directory) === 0) {
    // path OK
}
else {
    // path not ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how `../file.txt`  is supposed to turn into `/tmp/file.txt` in your example, but to check whether a path is a subpath of another, use [`realpath`](http://php.net/realpath) with a simple comparison:

```
$path = '../foo';
$allowedPath = '/tmp/';

$path = realpath($path);
if (substr($path, 0, strlen($allowedPath)) !== $allowedPath) {
    // path is not within allowed path!
}
```